# angular ng-repeat needs changes in data that is obtained from json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a JSON object that does not have proper data. So i want to replace the obtained value with one from a lookup table, but I'm not sure how to replace the value of the data corresponding to the lookup table.

```
lookupTable = {
  "pizza": function() {
    console.log("food");
  },
  "house": function() {
    console.log("building");
  },
  "air": function() {
    console.log("nothing");
  }
};
$scope.value =lookupTable["pizza"]()
```

my html file has

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{ x.lookupTable["pizza"]() }}</td>
```

My code is at http://plnkr.co/edit/w4lOFVRo9vSi8vqfbpXV?p=preview

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your lookup table is not returning anything except a function.. Which doesn't return anything but void (`console.log`).. Also, `names` is not defined ..

Comment: Do you mean how to restructure the JSON data?

Comment: What do you want to happen? Be very clear about your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is very confused. I tried to edit your [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9GbK38M3yaRkDUL58tfL?p=preview), maybe is easier to see that to explain.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<scriptsrc="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
        <td>{{ lookupTable[x.Name] }}</td> 
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get("data.json")
        .then(function(response) {
          $scope.names = response.data.records;
      });


    lookupTable = {
      "pizza": "food",
      "house": "building",
      "air": "nothing"
    };
    $scope.lookupTable = lookupTable;
    $scope.value = lookupTable["pizza"]
    console.log(lookupTable["house"]) 
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some problems in your code from the link you provided:

1. Functions on the `lookupTable` is not returning anything as pointed out in the previous answers.
2. `lookupTable` is not a property of `$scope.names` so using `x.lookupTable` is invalid.

To make it work, you should:

1. The functions from `lookupTable` should `return` the actual values instead of using `console.log`
2. Bind `lookupTable` to `$scope`
3. Use `lookupTable` directly inside the view as it is bound to `$scope`

Here is the relevant code:

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
      <td>{{ lookupTable[x.Name]() }}</td> 

    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("data.json")
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.names = response.data.records;
    });


    $scope.lookupTable = {
      "pizza": function() {
        return 'food';
      },
      "house": function() {
        return 'building';
      },
      "air": function() {
        return "nothing";
      }
    };

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I am not sure what you want to achieve.

The ng-repeat gives you three objects out of names, but none of them has a lookupTable member, so {{ x.lookupTable["pizza"] }} fails silently.

You can make it visible, if you just bind to {{ x }}